# How to bind or combine two objects in SceneKit

Tags: animation, scenekit

I have a bow and arrow. The arrow needs to look like it's on the bow and move with the bow until the arrow get shot forward. So how do I make an object always stay with the bow and move as the bow does, in other words temporarily combining the two? I'm currently using SceneKit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to make the arrow a child node of the bow. Or you can have a look at `SCNTransformConstraint`.